# Creating an 'Empty Shell' Jar

Tags: java, maven

I'm looking on guidance on how I can essentially create an 'empty shell' jar with maven. The idea is I have a java project, and I want to export the my.project.api classes (with package) into its own jar without saving the methods / constructors actual code inside.

For example, lets say I have the following:

```
public class Test {

  public void doSomething(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
  }

}
```

I want to export a separate jar which would keep its package declaration, and export as:

```
public class Test {

  public void doSomething(String message) {}

}
```

The reasoning for this is the project itself is exclusive, but I want to allow other developers to make their own integrations without the need of the physical product / project. This way by them hooking into say my.project.api.Test, they'd be able to see the methods and do as they wish.

Hopefully this clarifies enough, it would export as a separate jar maybe as 'MyProject-API.jar' or something.

Thanks!

Comment: the canonical answer to this would be to define the interface in one maven project (typically named <project>-api), and then put the implementation in another project.  This has the additional advantage of allowing you to explicitly manage and/or visualise api changes/support across versions.

Comment: Note especially: If you strip the instructions from a method that is _not_ `void`, the code will not compile any more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This very much looks like a use case for interfaces.

Comment: Is this not possible to just generate with maven? As said previously, I need another jar created as not every developer will gain access to the original jar (product).

Comment: Why not create a jar with the interfaces and then implement them in your "product "?

Comment: What about if I had a method that contained stored data?

Comment: I thought you wanted to have the methods _without_ the instructions?